# vim regex for python2 print to python3

Tags: regex, vim, python-2.7, printing, python-3.x

So say I have a python v2.7 file with some code like this:

```
print 'asdf'
print 'hi mom!'
```

But I want to run it in python3, I'll need to add those parenthesis to them like so:

```
print('asdf')
print('hi mom!')
```

I was trying to use the following regex in vim to solve the problem, but it wasn't working:

```
:%s/print\ '.*'/print('\1')/gc
```

It just gave me print functions (with parenthesis) that had empty strings.  Any help is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: For the love of all that is optimized and provable, please use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work for your examples

```
:%s/print \('.*'\)/print(\1)/g
```

1. You don't need to escape the space.
2. You don't actually capture anything in parenthesis so the `\1` is an empty string in your regex.

But I also recommend using [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Comment: Thanks, that is the regex that I was looking for.  I don't need something like '2to3', but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Benjamin if you are going to spend a lot of time using regexes in vim (if you use vim you will probably use them a lot) I would recommend reading or skimming a lot of `:h pattern-searches`