# regex (vim) for print ... to print(...) for python2 to python3

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, vim, python-3.3

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871086/vim-regex-for-python2-print-to-python3) is helpful only if you have strings inside of the print command. 
Now I have tons of sourcecode with a statement such as

```
print milk,butter
```

which should be formatted to

```
print(milk,butter)
```

And capturing the end of the line with \n was not sucessfull. Any hints?

Comment: As InspectorG4dget said on the linked question: use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Comment: Hint: You wouldn't capture the end of line with `\n`, you'd capture it with `$`.

Comment: jonrsharpe: Just assume I can only use vim

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not familiar with 2to3, but from all the comments, it looks like the correct tool for the job.

That said, perhaps we can use this question as an excuse for a short lesson in some vim basics.

First, you want a pattern that matches the correct lines.  I think that `^\s*print\>` will do:

- `^` matches start of line (and `$` matches end of line).
- `\s` matches whitespace (space or tab)
- `*` means 0 or more of the previous atom (as many as possible, or "greedy").
- `print` is a literal string.
- `\>` matches end-of-word (zero width). You might use a (literal) space or `\s\+` instead.

Next, you need to identify the part to be enclosed in parentheses.  Since `*` is greedy, `.*` will match to the end of the line; there is no need to anchor it on the right.  Use `\(\s*print\)` and `\(.*\)` to capture the pieces, so that you can refer to them as `\1` and `\2` in the replacement.

Now, put the pieces together.  There are many variants, and I have not tried to "golf" this one:

```
:%s/^\(\s*print\)\s\+\(.*\)/\1(\2)
```

Some people prefer the "very magic" version, where only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _ are treated as literal characters; then you do not need to escape the parentheses nor the plus:

```
:%s/^\v(\s*print)\s+(.*)/\1(\2)
```

Comment: Fix the print in current line by pressing F3 (shortcut for "f*** python 3): `nmap <F3> :s/^\(\s*print\)\s\+\(.*\)/\1(\2)<cr>` . Note: the regex is not suitable for converting a large amount of code, just for correcting the occasional mistake when you work with both python2 and python3 code.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) and only apply the fix for print statement -> print function.

```
2to3 --fix=print [yourfiles]
```

This should automatically handle all those strange cases which won't work with e.g. a vim regex.

If you are missing the `2to3` shell script for some reason, run the lib as a module:

```
python -m lib2to3 --fix=print [yourfiles]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you're in vim already:

```
:!2to3 --fix=print --write %
```